# Javascript client side MVC rendering responsibility

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I use an implementation of MVC for my client-side Javascript.

I have a `Table` model that contains an array of `Row` models. Each model has a corresponding view `TableView` and `RowView`.

```
var Table = function() {
   this.rows = [];
}
```

Responsibility for rendering the Table to the DOM resides with a `TableView` type. This accepts a `Table` model as a constructor argument.

To render itself it iterates over the `Row`s in the `rows` "instance variable", newing up a `RowView` for each, passing in the current row model and invokes render on the view like so:

```
var TableView = function(tableModel) {
    this.$el = $("#myTable");
    this.model = tableModel;

    this.render = function() {
      _.each(this.model.rows, function(row) { this.$el.append(new RowView(row).render()); });
    }
}
```

This works, but feels wrong because knowledge of the exact type of `RowView` being rendered resides with the table view. If I wanted to have another type of `RowView` - say `RowView2` that renders slightly differently, then I would need an explicit conditional in the `TableView` render function.

How could I change this implementation to enable polymorphic rendering of table rows - or is my implementation completely wrong-headed and there is a much better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could construct your `RowView` instances outside the `TableView` instance and pass them into the constructor in a list instead of the `TableModel` which you currently send. That way all `TableView` cares about is appending the element to the DOM and can do so regardless of the 'type' of `Row`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've looked into MVC libs, but here is a nice one from Peter Michaux: https://github.com/petermichaux/maria

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks interesting.